# What does "past" mean in this song?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "The Ballad of Flammingrad"
>
> Every December we all gather round
>   To pay our respects to a troll so renowned
>
> In remembrance of the friend we had
>   A jolly old soul we called Flemmingrad
>
> We all dig deep down
>   And we **uproot the past**
>   We shove up its nostril a fistful of grass
>   We shape his likeness, bless his soul
>   Oh, Flemmy the fungus troll
>
> *Lyrics from 'Olaf's Frozen Adventure'*

And it looks like this.
[image]

What does "past" mean here?

Comment: It doesn't have any special meaning, just the same one you can read in any dictionary.

Comment: if it means "the time or a period of time before the moment of speaking or writing" as a noun, then what does it mean by "uproot the past"? How can we uproot the past?

Comment: It's a metaphor. It's meaning is up to you to interpret. Many songs don't have very clear meanings.

Comment: Translate into your language: the past is a plant, grab the plant and pull it out of the ground. You will have uprooted the plant. Now, substitute the word past, not present or future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **bury the past** is a common metaphor for deliberately letting past events be forgotten or to refuse to discuss them any more.  The opposite of burying something is to dig it up; that is, to uproot it.  So **uprooting the past** here means deliberately remembering and re-examining past events that had been "buried".